# how to render html elements object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have object that create by document.createElement function

for example const elm = document.createElement('video')

but I don't how to render that element on react component

on render method of react component I return that object

```
render() {
   return elm;
}
```

but error is throw, can you help me?

Comment: What is the reason your using the DOM API instead of React? The whole point of React is not have to use that API.

Comment: I have use some stream api, and that api return video element, I need to attach that element to react element, but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Using this Way

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<h1>Hi there!</h1>" }} />
```